# Unable to connect in .NET Core 3.1 and 5, but working fine in .NET Framework 4.7.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, blazor-webassembly

#### Issue description

Unable to connect in .NET Core 3.1 and 5, but working fine in .NET Framework 4.7.2

```cs
  using (IDbConnection conn = new SnowflakeDbConnection())
            {
                conn.ConnectionString =  "scheme=https;ACCOUNT=Test;HOST=Test.us-east-1.snowflakecomputing.com;port=443; ROLE=PSR_USER_POC_ROLE;WAREHOUSE=DEMO_WH; USER=PSR_USER; PASSWORD=PSR_USER;DB=UTIL_DB;SCHEMA=PSR_USER_POC";
                conn.Open();

                conn.Close();
            }
```

#### Error log

```
 Snowflake.Data.Client.SnowflakeDbException: 'Snowflake Internal Error: Unable to connect. One or more errors occurred. (Request reach its timeout.)'
            
            SnowflakeDbException: Request reach its timeout.
            
            AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Request reach its timeout.)
```

There is an example in READMD.md file showing you how to enable logging.

Unable to connect in .NET Core 3.1 and 5, but working fine in .NET Framework 4.7.2

Added : Snowflake.Data 2.0.6

Comment: @BarışCanYılmaz that looks plenty of code to me - shows a connection being initialized and opened, which should work

Comment: @user3239484 if those credentials are real, please burn them immediately, before the internet kindly uses your credit for you

Comment: 1.  That's the code what I have....connectionstring issue.

Unable to open connection in.net core in 3.1 and 5

2. The same code in working fine in 4.7 standard framework 

3. Those are dummy username and password 

4. I have opened new blazor webassembly project.. I tried to connect, but I am getting error(Snowflake.Data.Client.SnowflakeDbException: 'Snowflake Internal Error: Unable to connect. One or more errors occurred. (Request reach its timeout.)'
   .. Is there something more has to be done in.net core 3.1 and 5

Comment: I just need connection string to connect snowflake by .NET CORE 3.1 or 5.
Just working code 1. ConnectionString 2.Open Connection 3.Close Connection.

Comment: @user3239484 there's no Blazor in .NET Framework so whatever you tried is completely different. Are you trying to connect from the client or server? If you try to connect from a Blazor WASM app you're connecting from the browser, which probably has no permissions to connect to the server. Perhaps the error is quite correct, and it's impossible to connect from the browser

Comment: @user3239484 put the relevant information in the question itself, not comments

Comment: If you have a Blazor WASM project, the browsers' IPs won't be on the server's whitelist and will be blocked. Blazor WASM creates Single Page Applications, no different than React, Angular or Vue. SPAs don't talk to databases directly for many reasons, including security. They talk to server APIs instead, which in turn talk to the database

Answer (score 1):

In .Net Core, use the Snowflake.Client library; See below code snippet.

```cs
public SnowflakeClient(string user, string password, string account, string region = null);
```

Configuration file:

```json
 "SnowflakeSettings": {

   "Account": "AB4444",

   "User": "SOME_SERVICE_ACCOUNT",

   "Password": "Password@123!",

   "Region": "east-us.azure"

  }
```

Thanks
Vam

Answer (score -1):

The Snowflake Connector for .NET connector has only been tested under .NET Framework 4.7.2 and .NET Standard 2.0.

It has not been tested under .NET 5.x or .NET core 3.x.

See [here](https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-net)

Comment: In other words, it does work on .NET Core and .NET 5. There's no .NET Standard 3. .NET Standard 2.0 is the common target that's used by .NET Framework and all supported versions of .NET Core (ie .NET Core 3.1, 5 and later). A library built for .NET Standard 20 works on both .NET Framework and all .NET Core versions since 2.0. There's no `.NET Framework 5`, .NET 5 is .NET *Core* 5

Comment: Except for Blazor Wasm, that targets (only) standard 2.1.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos,
Can u please provide 1 working sample project (Just Connection Open) for Blazor Project  3.1 and 5.

Comment: @user3239484 I already asked in the question's comments where the connection is made from. If you try to connect from the *browser*, you're trying to connect from an unknown IP that's almost certainly *not* in the server's or its firewall's whitelist. No client-side change is going to fix that. Blazor doesn't require different code

Comment: I have attached the project and error screenshots ..Kindly Help in connecting .NET Core 3.1 to snowflake......
Note : Same Code is working fine in .NET Framework 4.7.2.

https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ag8QU6ar3yRugYwhvslm2rQYKxe5Yg?e=NsERkt


https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ag8QU6ar3yRugYwiD7PwP_xsO3J4IQ?e=axecru
Error ScreenShots